# Read HTML on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that will read a lot of HTML source from a website.  The HTML source contains quite a bit of information, however the information I need is all stored in tr and td tags within the HTML like so:

```
  <tr>
            <td class="first">

            </td>
            <td >
                Origin
            </td>
            <td>
                  Airline
            </td>
            <td>
                Flight Number
            </td>
            <td>
                22 Feb 11:50
            </td>
            <td class="last">
                Arrived 12:35
            </td>
  </tr>
```

I intially thought about using the HTMLAgilityPack but it doesn't seem to be supported on Windows Phone 8, at least not without some fiddling with different settings.  I am reluctant to include a reference to that add-in as a result.

Is there another way for me to parse out the information I need?  Or will I just have to read through each line of HTML and pull out any text enclosed in tr and td tags?

If so, how do I read through the HTML?  I have it downloaded to a string, but I am unsure how to read through it.

Comment: Can you be sure the HTML looks like XHTML? If so, you can use an XmlReader. HTML5 also allows to omit the closing tags and a lot of stuff that makes parsing quite difficult

Comment: HAP doesn't work very well on WP, you can try compiling CsQuery (worked for me before), alternatively - use LINQ to XML. You can use a 'dirty' regex to extract a big chunk of HTML that _does_ look like XML and then use the XML parser to do the heavy lifting logic.

Comment: From looking at the information at the start of the page, it says XHTML - <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"

Comment: Looking at [the source](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest "Html Agility Pack - Source Code") seems to exist something for phone platforms. I fact, although I haven't tested it, I was able to add [the NuGet Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack "HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.6") to a Windows Phone 8 project.

Comment: I've decided not to use HAP.  I guess I am going to have to just download the HTML on the fly and parse out the information I want.  I tried the XML reader but didn't have much luck with it.

Comment: Actually I am trying the HAP now but I don't know how to parse the HTML above using it.  Could someone give me some pointers?