# HTML Agility Pack Usage on WP8

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

This question is a follow on from an earlier question I posted here about parsing HTML [Read HTML on Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957106/read-html-on-windows-phone-8?noredirect=1#comment33320524_21957106)

I am parsing a HTML page that has a ton of tr tags like this:

```
<tr>
        <td class="first">

        </td>
        <td >
            Origin
        </td>
        <td>
              Airline
        </td>
        <td>
            Flight Number
        </td>
        <td>
            22 Feb 11:50
        </td>
        <td class="last">
            Arrived 12:35
        </td>
</tr>
```

This is the code I am using to read the page and it's working fine:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td"))
{
    string item = node.ChildNodes[0].InnerHtml.Trim();
    lstResults.Items.Add(item)
}
```

The problem is, I want to concatenate each group of 5 TD values into one string.  At the moment, the code is adding each item individually into the lisbox, so I basically get 5 entries per flight like this:

```
FlightNumber
DueTime
arrival time
Origin
Airline
```

But instead I just want to add one entry per flight, something like this:

Origin - Airline - Flight Number - Due - Arrived

There is tr tag for each flight and inside each tr tag is the information shown above.  I'm not sure how to detect when I reach the end of the tag for a particular flight so I can group the information into one string, rather than adding each td tag individually.  There is a blank string at the start or end of each tr tag, but again I can't work out how to concatenate the values per td tag into one string, rather than adding each value on a seperate line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working actually using the implementation below.

```
HtmlNodeCollection table = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");

HtmlNodeCollection rows = table[0].SelectNodes("//td");

for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
{
    string flight = rows[i].InnerHtml.Trim();

    if (!flight.Contains(".jpg"))
    {
        item += flight + " - ";
    }
    else
    {
        lstFlights.Items.Add(item);
        item = "";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try adding an int that counts up to 5. Then from loops 1- 5 , add the results to a string or var. Then only on the 5th loop dump that variable to the list as a single item. You then want to reset your counter to 0 and begin again.

```
Int i =1;
String item = String.Empty;
foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td"))
{
    if(i =<5)
    {
      item += node.ChildNodes[0].InnerHtml.Trim();
      i++;
    }
    if (i == 5)
    {
      lstResults.Items.Add(item);
      i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, that seems to be causing some sort of infinite loop or causing the app to run out of memory.

Comment: Thats because I forgot to put the counter inside the first loop. Ive updated the code, give that a try.

Comment: Still no luck, it just seems to be adding the first entry over and over.  I think I need a different type of for loop, or one that moves along to the next node when it hits 5.